# Confused about how to use mutating

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I have a simple struct called `Card`...

```
struct Card {
    var order: Int? = -1
    var data : [String: String]
    var original : String?
```

And a collection object called `Deck` that looks like...

```
struct Deck {
    var cards : [Card]
```

Deck has the reading and writing methods, which basically boils down to splitting up strings read in from a text file, and then pushing it bit by bit into the previous empty `data`. Here's an example...

```
mutating func parseGRCard(var c: Card) {
    c.data["I1"] = c.original![2...4].trim()
    c.data["I2"] = c.original![5...9].trim()
}
```

To read the file, I get each line, make a `Card`, and then call the parse methods on it...

```
let nc = Card(order: i, original: c)
parseGRCard(nc)
cards.append(nc)
```

When I step through this func, I see that mc's `original` has the expected data, the original line from the text file. I then watch `parseGRCard` read it and add the items to `data`, which now has two items. But when when it returns and nc is appended, `data` is empty.

I thought `mutating` was supposed to handle these things, but apparently I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: isn't the purpose of mutating functions to mutate *member properties* of the structures? In your example, the argument of `parseGRCard(nc)` should still be passed by value (hence the mutating function, whereas allowed to mutate it's member properties, only performs operations on a local Card instance; it's single parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit to make it compile and make it more illustrative.

---

`append` is mutating because it mutates `cards`.
It's parameter `c` is an inout parameter so that the passed `Card` is passed back after the function. Since `Structs` are value types and not reference types a new copy is actually passed to the function. This behaviour has nothing to do with the function being a mutating function.

```
struct Card {
    var placeInDeck: Int = 0
}

struct Deck {
    var cards : [Card] = []

    mutating func append(inout c: Card) {
        c.placeInDeck = cards.count
        cards.append(c)
    }
}

var cardZero = Card()
var cardOne = Card()

var deck = Deck()

deck.append(&cardZero)
deck.append(&cardOne)

cardZero.placeInDeck // 0
cardOne.placeInDeck // 1
```

---

In this case the function is not mutating because no properties from `Deck` are altered. The `c` parameter is a variable which just makes it mutable inside the scope from the function. *Beware, this will be removed from Swift.* When the function ends, this mutable copy of `Card` will not update it's original instance outside the scope of the function. The updated `Card` will not persist.

```
struct Card {
    var placeInDeck: Int = 0
}

struct Deck {
    var cards : [Card] = []

    func updateCount(var c: Card) {
        c.placeInDeck = 1
    }
}

var cardZero = Card()
var cardOne = Card()

var deck = Deck()

deck.updateCount(cardZero)
deck.updateCount(cardOne)

cardZero.placeInDeck // 0
cardOne.placeInDeck // 0
```

Comment: Working! Ok so it seems my confusion is that the mutating isn't the answer, what I was looking for was `inout`. However, that requires the use of the &, at which point the syntax is a little funny. I'm wondering if using the struct in this case is worth the ugly.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz you can use a reference type or class. This requires no `inout`. Read up on OOP vs Functional Programming. A better grasp of these concepts will help you chose the best option for your patterns/functions

Comment: I'm such a slow writer it seems ;'( anyway, worth adding is that you can only use the `mutating` keyword on methods (not "stand-alone" functions), but in practice, all functions live in the scope of some class/structure and are hence, methods. For classes (which is probably the case for you, as you call the `parseGRCard(nc)` function directly), however, this keyword is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's documentation methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html), we can read the following regarding the `mutable` keyword:

> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
>   enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating
>   behavior for that method. The method *can then mutate (that is, change)
>   **its** properties from within the method*, and any changes that it makes
>   are written back to the original structure when the method ends.

I agree that it is could be possible to interpret the bold-marked part as as *"the properties of the method, i.e., it's parameters?"*. From your example above, it would seem as if you have done this interpretation.

But the mutable keyword only tells us that the associated function is allowed to change (mutate) variable member values of the struct (in this case) that owns the method.

```
struct SingleIntegerValueStruct1 {
    var myInt = 1
    func LetsTryToMutateTheInteger () {
        myInt += 1 // compile time error; myInt immutable
    }
}
```

Whereas if we use the mutating keyword

```
struct SingleIntegerValueStruct {
    var myInt = 0
    mutating func LetsTryToMutateTheInteger () {
        myInt += 1 // ok, mutating function
    }
}

var a = SingleIntegerValueStruct(myInt: 1)
print("\(a.myInt)") // 1
a.LetsTryToMutateTheInteger()
print("\(a.myInt)") // 2
```

However, a `struct` type is and will always be a value type. So when when a `struct` type is passed to any function, the function will not be able to mutate the caller parameter, as it is only given a copy of it.

```
let nc = Card(order: i, original: c)
parseGRCard(nc)  // passes _copy_ of struct typ nc to parseGRCard
cards.append(nc) // nc in this scope is stil unchanged
```

---

For wanting to use a *"stand-alone"* function that could mutate its input parameter, where the input is a struct, you could, as discussed in the comments, us the `inout` keyword on the function parameter.

We extend our example from above to include such a case:

```
struct SingleIntegerValueStruct {
    var myInt = 0
    mutating func LetsTryToMutateTheInteger () {
        myInt += 1 // ok, mutating function
    }

}

// "b" here is a _copy_ of "a" (in parameter), and the function
// thereafter returns a _copy_ of "b" (with state of "b" as its 
// final state in the function)
func standAloneInOutFunction(inout b: SingleIntegerValueStruct) {
    b.LetsTryToMutateTheInteger()
}

var a = SingleIntegerValueStruct(myInt: 1)
print("\(a.myInt)") // 1
a.LetsTryToMutateTheInteger()
print("\(a.myInt)") // 2
standAloneInOutFunction(&a) 
    // value copy a->b, modify(b), value copy back b->a
print("\(a.myInt)") // 3
```

Note however that the `inout` keyword does not mean that we pass by *reference* (as for class instances), but we simply send a value copy in and takes another value copy back, that we finally assigns to the original value type calling parameter (a).

From the [Apple documentation on this keyword](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> ... An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function,
>   is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to
>   replace the original value.

Comment: So to make sure I understand this: the problem is that the c inside the func is not the same one I passed in, but a copy which disappears when it returns. That part I understood. Am I correct that inout and the passing the address is the solution? If so, it seems worse than the problem, it would seem using a class would result in much cleaner code.

Comment: I extended my answer to answer this to you. Note that you do no pass an adress, by still a copy. And yes, perhaps this is as good reason as any for you, in this certain case, to switch to a class instead.

Comment: Ok I think I get it all now. There are two ways to solve this, either move the methods into the struct and mark them mutating OR use inout and the &. I already switch to a class, but maybe I'll try this anyway. I'm still not 100% clear on the data in the struct, is that part of the struct and mutating/inout works, or is it its own object that will also disappear on copy-back?

Comment: The whole struct is sent by value (copied), including all properties in struct. So when using inout with struct as parameter, you send a "full" value copy to the function (including properties), and then send the copy (after possible changing it within the function) as a copy to the caller, where the last copy will be assigned to the variable name that was used as parameter in (now overwritten by out). The mutating functions are used mainly to access struct properties, which are otherwise non-mutable.

Comment: Ok, that is very useful. I got myself into this because I was going to deprecate the Card in favor of a simple dictionary holding the information, which led me to move the parsing over to Deck, and then into this black hole. For the future, I will try to use struct (and as I say, may re-convert this code back) and be sure to use methods on the stuct and mutate.

Comment: One step back, two steps forward, the joy of learning new stuff :) good luck!